# ng-show ng-hide angular questions-answer

Tags: angularjs

I have a website where i show different questions and when you click in one appear the answer and if you click again dissapear. And i trying to do it in
Angular but for the moment i can't achive it.

```
<ul id="question-list">
        <li>
            <h1><a ng-click="answer = !answer" >What is this?</a></h1>
            <h3 ng-show="answer"> this</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h1 >What is the question?</h1>
            <h3>It </h3>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h1>What is the question?</h1>
            <h3> Ipsum.</h3>
        </li>
```

Angular Code

```
ehlApp.controller('faqController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.answer = true;

});
```

Comment: What does your angular code look like?

Comment: $scope.answer = true;

Comment: Can you post all the code. Everything you've posted so far is correct

Comment: what is the problem with your code, is your logic is not working, i had checked in my local it works as you expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted worked perfectly in a properly set up app, so I'm guessing that's the problem.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <ul id="question-list">
        <li>
            <h1><a ng-click="answer = !answer">What is this?</a></h1>
            <h3 ng-show="answer"> this</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h1>What is the question?</h1>
            <h3>It </h3>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h1>What is the question?</h1>
            <h3> Ipsum.</h3>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<script>

    var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.answer = true;
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Each question have there own answers so to display the answer attached jsbin
HTML :

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
   <ul id="question-list" >
     <li ng-repeat = "questionAns in vm.questionList">
      <h1 ng-click="questionAns.showAnswer = !questionAns.showAnswer">             <a ng-bind="questionAns.question"></a></h1>
        <h3 ng-show="questionAns.showAnswer" ng-bind="questionAns.answer"></h3>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
     var vm = this;
     vm.questionList = [{
       "question" : "What is this question 1?",
       "answer" : "this is answer1"
     },{
       "question" : "What is this question 2?",
       "answer" : "this is answer2"
     }];
}]);
```

[jsbin to show hide](https://jsbin.com/tofokucoxa/3/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that all in the template, example:

```
<p ng-click="x=!x">Something<span ng-show="x"> else</span>.</p>
```

Clicking on the `<p>` will make the `<span>` show and disappear.

Comment: If you wanted the text to be displayed by default then you would have to use `ng-init` as well

Comment: Or use `ng-hide` instead of `ng-show` (but agreed, `ng-init` would be cleaner).

Answer (score -1):

```
   <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="control">
     <ul id="question-list">
        <li>
            <h1><a ng-click="answer = !answer">What is this?</a></h1>
            <h3 ng-show="answer"> this</h3>
        </li>
        ,<li>
            <h1 ng-click="answer = !answer">What is the question?</h1>
            <h3 ng-show="answer">It </h3>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h1 ng-click="answer = !answer">What is the question?</h1>
            <h3 ng-show="answer"> Ipsum.</h3>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<script>
   var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    app.controller('control', function ($scope) {
        $scope.answer = true;
    });

</script>
```